# How to get array values Into another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function where I can get the table rows values and store into array and return this array. I want to use this array return values into another function but I got error like underdefined 0,underdefined length. I try multiple options like `$.each` method, for loop and last one called direct array but can't get result.

```
function rowData(btn_id){
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', btn_id, function () {

        var getdata = $(this).closest('tr').children("td").map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();

        console.log(getdata);
        return getdata;

        });
    });
}
var all = rowData(".edit_minor_cate");
alert(all[0]);
```

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: why you use Jquery ready method inside the rowData method?

Comment: You can not return data from a click event inside of a function call.

Comment: How we can do it ? I want to get the all column value's when we click on that row btn and use it where we want inside others functions ?

Comment: There is no error regarding "underdefined" in JavaScript -- there is "undefined" however. Perhaps you could include the actual error messages? You may want also include an example of the HTML on which the code works. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to create a runnable snippet so that others can see the errors you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="data"> Hello, I am data 1 </td>
      <td class="data"> Hello, I am data 2 </td>

    </tr>
  </table>

  <button id="button_id">click me</button>
</div>
```

And JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', "#button_id", function () {
        var getdata = $('.data').map(function(){
               return $.trim($(this).text());
            }).get();
        console.log(getdata[0]);
        alert(getdata[1]);
    });
});
```